# Flickr available only through phone. Can't reset password

Tags: flickr, authentication, account-management

I can access the account from my phone, but I'm not able to save any pictures. I can't access my account from the web because I created it using Google. Then when I didn't know how to get my pictures back I created new account with the same Google and got a different ID. Now I can't login to my Flickr to retrieve pictures although I can still view them from my android phone.

I've tried to contact customer services since 9 Feb, 2011. But all they answer me is to "upgrade your account by going to `mail.yahoo.com` " they aren't reading that I *can't login*.

How can I retrieve my images? They are very valuable to me!

Answer (score 3):

Head over to the [login help page](http://www.flickr.com/help/with/login/), click on `Help by email` & [fill up the form](https://www.flickr.com/help/with/login/send/)

[image]

[image]

Provide your flickr profile/account page URL & they'll tell you which login ID you used to create the account.